# Whose face is seen in "They shall see his face"? Rev 22v4 ESV

Tags: word-study

"They will see his face, and his name will be on their foreheads". Revelation 22:4. ESV

"..with him 144,000 who had his name and his Father's name written on their foreheads". Revelation 14:1. ESV

If the name of the Father and the Son is one name-God-then maybe the face of the Father and the Son is one face. "In the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Ghost" maintains togetherness and distinctiveness.

"This is my beloved Son with whom I am well pleased". Matthew 3:17. Here "I" and "Son" are distinct.

A. Is Revelation 22:4 talking about one or two faces? [Quantity not quality].

B. If it could be the Father's face or the Son's face which might it be?

Comment: Since Revelation is attributed to John, perhaps John 14:9 might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that sinners cannot see the face of God the Father (Ex 33:20-23, John 1:18), there are creatures untouched by the curse of sin that an and do see the face of God as recorded by Jesus Himself:

> Matt 18:10 - " … For I tell you that their angels in heaven always see
>   the face of my Father in heaven."

Significantly, the text of Rev 22:4 is immediately preceded by v3 which says that, "No longer will there be any curse."  This is a direct fulfilment of a number of prophetic promises that the redeemed righteous will see God's face:

- Job 33:26 - Then he will pray to God, and He will accept him, That he may see His face with joy, And He may restore His righteousness to man.
- Ps 11:7 - For the LORD is righteous, He loves righteousness; The upright will behold His face.
- 1 John 3:2 - Beloved, now we are children of God, and it has not appeared as yet what we will be. We know that when He appears, we will be like Him, because we will see Him just as He is.

Lastly, we are told that the righteous saved will have the name of God the Father written on their foreheads in Rev 3:12 and 14:1.  This enables us to unambiguously identify the antecedent for the pronoun "his" in Rev 22:4 "they shall see his face" because it is the same as "his name is on their foreheads".

Thus, the saved righteous, free of the curse of sin, will see the face of God and have His name on their foreheads.  Here, the name of "God" presumably includes both the Father and the Lamb.

Comment: As in the question Rev14:1 does not isolate the Father because "the Lamb...had his name and his Father's name written on their foreheads".

Comment: That is true but observe several things:  Rev 3:12 definitely records that it is the Father's name and the other evidence listed above appears to identify the Father as well.  In any case, Matt 28:19 uses the singular "name" for Father Son and Holy Spirit.

Comment: Rev 3:12 says, "I will write on them the name of my God", if Jesus is speaking, then this must be the Father.

Comment: Quite correct.  Taking a que from Matt 28:19, perhaps the name (singular) is the name of both Father and Son??